# Some fonts used in this document are missing. How to solve it?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop CC I have opened a .psd file. But a window with a title "Missing Fonts" appeared.

[image]

If I understand right, Photoshop needs a "Lobster" font. I use Windows 7, I've downloaded a Lobster font and installed it system-wide. I have also included Lobster_1.3.otf into the /fonts folder of the folder where my project lives and all the other fonts used in .psd files. So it has to see that font. However the window appears. How to solve it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Some fonts used in this document are missing. How to solve it?](http://superuser.com/questions/815470/some-fonts-used-in-this-document-are-missing-how-to-solve-it). Please don't double post questions on other Stack Exchange sites. It adds confusion when they are migrated to the proper site.